# IOS UITableViewCell - Swiping Sections

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a brief that requires a swiping panel view to display a staged fitness plan event - basically I need something that swipes uitableview sections horizontally similar to the way the suggested Apps panel works - i'd need to use custom cells - no idea if this is possible as I cant find any information anywhere to guide me - does anyone have any experience or can offer any advice!?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

At the simplest level you can just stick a `UIScrollView` in the cell. If you need to put a lot of elements in there and performance is a concern you would use a `UICollectionView` with a layout like the built in `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` with horizontal scrolling. Then, each of those elements would just be a `UICollectionViewCell`.